# how to represent members in a list of list as a list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list of lists. How can I get a specific index members in each element as a list without using a loop and assignment. Below code snippet is an example. Actual list contains more than 3 sublists. Output should be like a list say mem_lst given below.

```
    alst = [['abc', 1 , 2], ['cde', 2, 2], ['xyz', 2, 2]]
    o/p: mem_lst = [ 'abc', 'cde', 'xyz']
```

Comment: `list(map(itemgetter(0), alst))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: alst = [['abc', 1 , 2], ['cde', 2, 2], ['xyz', 2, 2]]

In [2]: import operator

In [3]: map(operator.itemgetter(0), alst)
Out[3]: <map at 0x104b43160>

In [4]: list(_)
Out[4]: ['abc', 'cde', 'xyz']
```

In this approach you don't use loop, and you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as a iterator to avoiding storage of `list`, but if you strongly need a `list`, just need to wrap it in [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

Comment: @Aragon what are you trying to achieve? Unpack whole list? What's your desired output?

Comment: same issue.. it's working only for 0th item not for other indices. like



        [ ['/backup1', 'amitn', '159', ''], 
        ['/backup1', 'ashok', '407', ''], 
        ['/backup1', 'aswathy', '66', ''], 
        ['/backup1', 'CRL_DATA', '93', ''] ]

        o/p: ['amitn', 'ashok', 'aswathy', CRL_DATA]

Comment: If you need to iterate over particular index, you need to put in `operator.itemgetter(<your_index>)`

Comment: its not working.. i tried with operator and item from previous answer

Comment: `mem_list = list ( map ( operator.itemgetter( 1 ), usr ) )`
        `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `usr` must have a sublist with only one item

Comment: @Aragon then one of your list elements does not contain at least 2 elements, you need to check that.

Comment: oh yes i made d same guess. detected the error. one empty sublist was present. Thank you every one

Comment: Oh, wow, downvote, really? My dear downvoter, can you, please, be so kind to explain how this answer is __Not usefull__?

Answer (score -1):

You could do this, in python 2.x,

**zip(*alst)[0]**

```
>>> lst = [['abc', 1, 2], ['cde', 2, 2], ['xyz', 2, 2]]
>>> zip(*lst)[0]
('abc', 'cde', 'xyz')
>>>
```

In python 3, you can do it just like this,

**list(zip(*alst))[0]**

```
>>> lst
[['abc', 1, 2], ['cde', 2, 2], ['xyz', 2, 2]]
>>> list(zip(*lst))[0]
('abc', 'cde', 'xyz')
>>>
```

Comment: its working for 0th element but not for other indices. if i want

Comment: this is not working..
        mem_list  = [item[1] for item in alst]

Comment: [item[1] for item in alst] prints every 2nd element of each member of alst.

Comment: OP mentioned without loop, but in your answer I can see you have used loop, why is that ? correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score -1):

Without any kind of a loop:

```
alst = [['abc', 1 , 2], ['cde', 2, 2], ['xyz', 2, 2]]
lst = [alst[0][0],alst[1][0],alst[2][0]]
print(lst)
```

Comment: that was an sample pal.. the list contains more than 3 items

Comment: @Aragon You should put that in the question. See [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood ok sir

Comment: sorry didnt get the question well i thought that was the whole list

Comment: it was my fault. I should hv mentioned. anyways thanks

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.